fixing wierd black spots for animation reveal object
hi i made animation reveal for my projects but in transparent mode i saw these weird black spots on my mesh i dont know this is shodow or what , how to fix this ? enter image description here



The question has been asked many times, see this question but look my second answer there, because the accepted one is wrong (for that question): Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?. It is basically like this: many transparent objects need many Transparent bounces, transmissive materials like glass need Transmission bounces and many reflective objects need more Glossy bounces. And for Transmission and Glossy you have to increase Total as well.

If these are more glass-like objects rather than ones with alpha transparency, take a look at my more in-depth explanation on improving glass renders in my answer here: Glass render is black for some reason

Tnx Man   made my day
